# XML file that xls can read python

Tags: python, xml, excel

I have xml  [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ib-jzdAAmqG7EUsf2osAY_h1IGFrQoEE/view?usp=sharing)

If i rename it in xls, i can open it in office excel but i cant read it in python using xlrd or openpyxl libs.

How can I convert it to xls or xlsx so i could open it in python?

UPD_1:

tried to use xml2xlsx lib, but final xlsx file is empty. Here is my code:

```
from pprint import pprint
import os
from xml2xlsx import xml2xlsx
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

template = open(BASE_DIR + '\\111.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
f = open(BASE_DIR + '\\test.xlsx', 'wb')
f.write(xml2xlsx(template))
f.close()
```

Comment: can you open & save as xlsx using excel? then you could read it with openpyxl.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/pkaczynski/xml2xlsx  ?

Comment: @Rikusor, ty, but it didnt helped